# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am passing my values from a gridview to a different page row-wise.The table for the gridview in the database is as follows:

```
 Create table Task
  (
    TaskId int Identity(1,1),
     Title varchar(100),
     Body varchar(500),
     Reward decimal(4,2),
    TimeAllotted int,
    PosterName varchar(100)
  )
```

the code -behind for the details page is as below:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView1 = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView1");
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        lblTaskId.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
        lblTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        lblBody.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        lblReward.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        lblTimeAllotted = row.Cells[4].Text;
        lblPosterName = row.Cells[5].Text;


    }
}
```

It displays everything as desired but when I click on 'view task' in a particular row of the gridview, I get an exception Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'. The exception occurs on the last two lines i.e

```
    lblTimeAllotted = row.Cells[4].Text;
    lblPosterName = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblTimeAllotted.text = row.Cells[4].Text;
lblPosterName.text = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

You cant set a label to a text. You need to set the text property of the label

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a `string` to a `Label`. You have to set the value to property `Text` of both labels:

```
lblTimeAllotted.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
lblPosterName.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have:

```
    lblTaskId.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
    lblTitle.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
    lblBody.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
    lblReward.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
```

Followed by:

```
lblTimeAllotted = row.Cells[4].Text;
lblPosterName = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

I presume that what you actually mean is:

```
lblTimeAllotted.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
lblPosterName.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

The reason you are seeing the exception is that .NET is trying to change your label objects to the string value of the cells, which is obviously nonsensical. Looks like a simple typo :)